# Forward packages over openvpn and ipsec in strongswan container in docker in Kubernetes

Tags: iptables, openvpn, kubernetes, ipsec

I am running a deployment with an IPsec(strongswan) and an OpenVPN container.

Configuration of IPsec:

```
config setup

conn customer
    keyexchange=ikev1
    left=%defaultroute
    leftsubnet=192.168.224.0/24
    right=X.X.X.X
    rightsubnet=10.5.0.0/16
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp3072!
    esp=aes256-sha256-modp3072!
    authby=psk
    ikelifetime=28800
    lifetime=3600
    auto=start
    type=tunnel
```

ipsec-start-sh:

```
    ip link add name eth1 type dummy
    ifconfig eth1 up
    ip addr add 192.168.224.1 dev eth1
    ifconfig eth1 mtu 1440
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    iptables -I FORWARD -s 0/0 -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
    ipsec start
```

IPsec is functional!

I can ping a server on the other side of the IPsec.

openvpn configuration:

```
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/vpn.seeberger.adito.cloud.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/vpn.seeberger.adito.cloud.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 10.5.0.0 255.255.0.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "route 10.5.0.0 255.255.0.0"
#push "block-outside-dns"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"

ifconfig: 
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/vpn.seeberger.adito.cloud.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/vpn.seeberger.adito.cloud.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto udp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 10.5.0.0 255.255.0.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "route 10.5.0.0 255.255.0.0"
#push "block-outside-dns"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4A:1C:D3:AB:2E:DE  
          inet addr:10.42.74.74  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::481c:d3ff:feab:2ede/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1440  Metric:1
          RX packets:1454 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:234613 (229.1 KiB)  TX bytes:26814 (26.1 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9E:B3:59:1F:3A:03  
          inet addr:192.168.224.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::9cb3:59ff:fe1f:3a03/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1440  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:70 (70.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:192.168.255.1  P-t-P:192.168.255.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::a4c1:6d34:21b:1d7a/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:240 (240.0 B)  TX bytes:304 (304.0 B)
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         169.254.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.5.0.0        192.168.255.2   255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.255.0   192.168.255.2   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.255.2   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Can you help me with the iptable routes to route traffic from tun0 to the ipsec-tunnel, so I ping a server (e.g. 10.5.1.170) from my local pc to the server on the other end of the ipsec-tunnel?

---edit---

openvpnclient-ip:
192.168.255.6

tcpdump on ipsec-container:
ping openvpn-container -> 10.5.1.170 (working!)

```
13:33:18.347397 IP 10.42.74.71.4500 > X.X.X.X.4500: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xb6ab40ec,seq=0x15), length 136
13:33:18.358348 IP X.X.X.X.4500 > 10.42.74.71.4500: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcd9b9abe,seq=0x16), length 136
13:33:18.358348 IP 10.5.1.170 > 192.168.224.1: ICMP echo reply, id 8192, seq 0, length 64
```

ping openvpn-client -> 10.5.1.170 (not working!)

```
13:27:03.644454 IP 192.168.255.6 > 10.5.1.170: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 952, length 40
```

X.X.X.X is the ip of the other company

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Jofu

Comment: What's again missing is the IP address of your local client.

Comment: Do you mean the ip adress i'm getting from OpenVPN? The IP address is 192.168.255.6

Answer (score 0):

This can't work. Your IPsec tunnel is between the subnets `192.168.224.0/24` and `10.5.0.0/16`. A packet with source IP `192.168.255.6` does not match that IPsec policy so it is dropped.

If you can't change the IPsec policy (so it covers these packets), you could maybe NAT packets from `192.168.255.0/24` to an IP in `192.168.224.0/24` so the policy matches.